# Enable 5.1 Sound in Windows

Tags: windows, audio, hdmi, 5.1

I have connected my MatePro Laptop to my Panasonic TV which is connected to Panasonic Home Cinema by HTML cable. However, the sound is placed only in Stereo format and I cannot select 5.1 channel sound as displayed below.

What can I do to be able to have surrounding sound enabled?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should connect it to the Home Cinema instead by the “HDMI” cable and select the TV output to Home Cinema, that might help.

Comment: Is the TV definitely 5.1-capable? What's the exact model?

Comment: @Valay_17 the sound is played through the Home Cinema. Home Cinema does not have an HTDI out port to transfer video to TV. It has just one port for sound.

Comment: connecting home cinema to laptop via HDMI does not work at all. it's not detected as a speaker.

Comment: Including the model for both TV and Home Cinema will help a lot.